# Conditional expectation of function of two independent random variables

Tags: conditional-expectation

Let $X,Y$ two real independent random variables. I need to compute
$$\mathbb E[e^\frac{X}{Y}|Y]$$
which as we know is a measurable function of $Y$. Now, for every $y$  **fixed** I am able to compute
$$\mathbb E[e^\frac{X}{y}]=\phi(y)$$
which is a function of $y$. Now one would expect that, by independence of $X$ and $Y$,
$$\mathbb E[e^\frac{X}{Y}|Y]=\phi(Y)$$
but I haven't found any property that says that for the conditional expectation. Is there any theorem that I could apply?

Comment: A more general proof which implies your question can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2992868/948397).